# ' <--- in mysql text don't get inserted in database

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Hello i'm a beginner so please at least try to give me a hint,a example.

- English isn't my main language so please endure it.

If somebody type `" Hello my name is J'hon '` the text don't insert in database, but if he type `'Hello my name is jhon'` it does. I think it is something about '

Ok so i'm having the problem that if someone types

`'Hello my name is J[color=#FF0000]'[/color]hon J'onz. '` is not inserted in the database..

This is the script:

```
mysqli_query($DB_H, "INSERT INTO tickets (name, continutscurt, continut,type,status) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['username']."', '".$_POST['titlu']."', '".$_POST['continut']."', $numar, 0)");
```

Comment: Instead of using all of those $_ variables and having to deal with the single/double quote problems - why not assign them to variables FIRST and then use the temporary variables?  Like $username, $tifu, etc... Also, don't forget about SQL injections. So either bin2hex and unhex your values or use one of the checkers provided for MySQL. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: @MarkManning Great comment! My answer explained the single/double quote problem and the issue with unhexing the values. It's easier to use established CSS practices.

Comment: Please give me a website to learn more about this! I don't understand what do you mean ? i want to learn how to create a safe-insert text

Comment: I suggest you learn how to use Prepared Statements for your SQL calls instead of simply joining the strings together. It's a much better technique for many reasons.

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: @StateValentin: I recommend you check out the "Open Web Application Security Project".  [**SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: @ProgrammingTree And the issue with unhexing is????

Answer (score 4):

You should really use prepared statements when dealing with any kind of user-input. If you for any weird reason isn't using prepared statements, take a look at the function `mysqli::real_escape_string`. This will deal with special characters, such as `'`, which may break the SQL.

With using prepared statements, your code would look like

```
if ($stmt = $DB_H->prepare("INSERT INTO tickets (`name`, continutscurt, continut, `type`, `status`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssi", $_SESSION['username'], $_POST['titlu'], $_POST['continut'], $numar, 0);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    echo mysqli_error($DB_H);
}
```

If you however want to use `mysqli::real_escape_string`, you'll need to bind the SESSIONs and POSTs to a variable where in you insert instead, like this (you can also do it directly in the query, but this makes for cleaner code).

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string ($DB_H, $_SESSION['username']); 
$titlu = mysqli_real_escape_string ($DB_H, $_POST['titlu']); 
$continut = mysqli_real_escape_string ($DB_H, $_POST['continut']); 
$numar = mysqli_real_escape_string ($DB_H, $numar);

if (!mysqli_query($DB_H, "INSERT INTO tickets (`name`, continutscurt, continut, `type`, `status`) VALUES ('$username', '$titlu', '$continut', '$numar', 0")) { 
    echo mysqli_error($DB_H); 
}
```

---

I also put backticks ` around `name`, `status` and `type`, as these are keywords in SQL. This isn't strictly necessary, but it's good practice with words that are listed as either reserved words or keywords, more info on [this list of keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html).

---

You shouldn't take for granted that your queries are successful, so I added an `if`-block around them. Errors shouldn't be displayed unless in production/development.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: I removed my quibble based on the edit. If we use backticks, we don't have to fiddle with worrying about whether `name` is a *reserved word* or just a keyword. Just wrap it in backticks, and the problem avoided. +10 Good answer.

Comment: I noticed ;-) Thanks, and likewise!

Comment: Thank you very much Qirel!!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is SQL Injection.

You have potentially unsafe values being included within the SQL text.

To see this, break up the code a little bit.

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO tickets ...'" . $val . "' ... ";
  echo $sql;
```

The `echo` is there just as a way to see what's going on, for you to examine the contents of the string containing the SQL text.  And then take that string over to another client, and test it. And you will see what the the problem is.

```
   ... VALUES ( ..., 'J'onz. ', ...
```

isn't valid. That single quote is ending the string, so the string is just 'J', and the next part, MySQL is going to try to interpret as part of the SQL, not the string value.  (This is a nefarious vulnerability. Cleverly constructed strings and wreak havoc on your application and your database.)

One approach to fixing that is to sanitize the values, so they can be safely included.

```
   ... VALUES ( ..., 'J\'onz. ', ...
                       ^^

   ... VALUES ( ..., 'J''onz. ', ...
                       ^^
```

As a simple demonstration try these queries:

```
 SELECT 'J\'onz. '
 SELECT 'J''onz. '
 SELECT 'J'onz. '
```

(The first two will return the string you expect, and the third will cause an error.)

The take away is that potentially unsafe values that are going to included in the text of a SQL statement need to be properly escaped.  Fortunately, the MySQL client library includes `mysqli_real_escape_string` function. Variables that may potentially contain a single quote character can be run through that function, and the return from the function can be included in the SQL text.

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO tickets ...'" 
         . mysqli_real_escape_string($DB_H,$val)
         . "' ... ";
```

Again, echo out the `$sql` and you can see that a single quote has been escaped, either by preceding it with a backslash character, or replacing it with two sinqle quotes.

---

There's a much better pattern than "escaping" strings. And that's to use **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders**.

The SQL text can be a static string:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO mytable (mycol) VALUES ( ? )'
```

And then you `msyqli_prepare` the statement.

And then supply values for the placeholders with a call to `mysqli_bind_param`.

And then call `mysqli_execute`.

With this pattern, we don't need to mess with running the "escape string" function to sanitize the inputs.

Comment: Awesome answer Spencer! One problem, you can still INSERT data with SQL even if it's not sanitized or secure? It may be more safe, but this isn't the solution...

Comment: @ProgrammingTree: I'm sure there's more than one problem. If we need to store "O'Reilly" as a value, certainly, we need to allow that. Certainly, it's possible for custom code to perform additional checking of allowable values. But in terms of the approaches I outlined ( real_escape_string, and prepared statements with bind placeholders), these *are* generally accepted as the right solutions.

Comment: A very thorough answer, and it answers this question as well. I don't see why it was downvoted? Upvoted it!